# Restler custom routes

Tags: php, url-routing, restler

We're exploring the Restler framework. What we need is a custom route like:

```
[host]/:sessionid/{class}/{method}?param1=x&param2=y
```

For example, the `Settings` method in the `Game` class:

```
<?php
class Game {
    function settings($session, $sound=TRUE, $music=TRUE){
        //
    }
}
?>
```

should map to `http://hostname/12435635/game/settings?sound=x&music=y`

We've managed to achieve it by hacking the `routes.php` file a bit, but as the file is auto-generated the idea is not very good. So, is it possible to create such routes without hacking the Restler's source or modifying the `routes.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to remove class name from the URI. It can be achieved by modifying the `addAPIClass` statement

```
$r->addAPIClass('Game', '');
```

this changes the auto generated uri structure as follows

```
http://hostname/settings/12435635/?sound=x&music=y
```

Next step is to specify a route manually by adding a PHPDoc comment to the api method as shown below

```
<?php
class Game {

    /**
    * @url GET /:session/game/settings
    */
    function settings($session, $sound=TRUE, $music=TRUE){
        //
    }
}
```

This will map to

```
http://hostname/12435635/game/settings?sound=x&music=y
```

This route will be added to `routes.php` every time it is generated in production mode :)

You may add more @url comments to create multiple routes to the same method